# Difficulty inputting training dataset with python code

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, machine-learning

Please, I need help with this. Tried almost everything I know and nothing is working.
So I am working on carrying out performance evaluation on dendritic cell algorithm used to detect anomalies by accepting input signals(PAMP, Danger signals, Safe Signals) the project is based on using parameter tuning to carry out this analysis. Changing the algorithm parameters and evaluate each result.

Got the algorithm's ruby code from the book "clever algorithms" and converted it to python.

My problem is that I am finding it difficult inputting my dataset on the python code, I am using the Nsl-kdd'cup dataset.

Also, help on using this with Matlab will be much appreciated.

Please, I need help.
The python code

```
from random import randrange,random,randint
def rand_in_bounds(min,max):
    return randrange(min, max)

# def random_vector(search_space): unused function
#   arr=np.zeroes(5)
#   return arr

def construct_pattern(class_label,domain,p_safe,p_danger):
    set_=domain[class_label]
    selection=randrange(len(set_))
    pattern={}
    pattern["class_label"]=class_label
    pattern["input_"]=set_[selection]
    pattern["safe"]=(random()*p_safe*100)
    pattern["danger"]=(random()*p_danger*100)
    return pattern

def generate_pattern(domain,p_anomaly,p_normal,prob_create_anom=0.5):
    pattern=None
    if random() < prob_create_anom:
        pattern=construct_pattern("Anomaly",domain,1-p_normal,p_anomaly)
        print(">Generated Anomaly",pattern["input_"])
    else:
        pattern=construct_pattern("Normal",domain,p_normal,1-p_anomaly)
    return pattern

def initialize_cell(thresh):
    cell={}
    cell["lifespan"]=1000
    cell["k"]=0
    cell["cms"]=0
    cell["migration_threshold"]=thresh[0]+((thresh[1]-thresh[0])*random())
    cell["antigen"]={}
   # print(cell)
    return cell

def store_antigen(cell,input_):
    cell["antigen"].setdefault(input_,0)
    cell["antigen"][input_]+=1


def expose_cell(cell,cms,k,pattern,threshold):
    cell["cms"]+=cms
    cell["k"]+=k
    cell["lifespan"]-=cms
    store_antigen(cell,pattern["input_"])
    if cell["lifespan"]<=0 : cell= initialize_cell(threshold)

def can_cell_migrate(cell):
    return (cell["cms"]>=cell["migration_threshold"]) and 
(len((cell["antigen"]))!=0)

def expose_all_cells(cells,pattern,threshold):
    migrate=[]
    cms=(pattern["safe"]+pattern["danger"])
    k=pattern["danger"]-(pattern["safe"]*2)
    for cell in cells:
        expose_cell(cell,cms,k,pattern,threshold)
        if can_cell_migrate(cell):
            cell["class_label"]=("Anomaly" if cell["k"]>0 else "Normal")
            migrate.append(cell)
    print("________________________")
    return migrate

def train_system(domain,max_iter,num_cells,p_anomaly,p_normal,thresh):
    immature_cells=[] 
    immature_cells=[initialize_cell(thresh) for x in range(num_cells)]
    migrated=[]
    c=0
    for x in range(max_iter):
        pattern=generate_pattern(domain,p_anomaly,p_normal)
        migrants=expose_all_cells(immature_cells,pattern,thresh)
        for cell in migrants:
            immature_cells=[ x for x in immature_cells if x is not cell]
            immature_cells.append(initialize_cell(thresh)) 
            migrated.append(cell) 

        c+=1
        print(f'> iter= {c}  new={len(migrants)}  migrated={len(migrated)}')  

    return migrated

def classify_pattern(migrated,pattern):
    input_=pattern["input_"]
    num_cells,num_antigen=0,0
    for cell in migrated:
        if ((cell["class_label"]=="Anomaly") and (input_ in cell["antigen"])):
            num_cells+=1
            num_antigen+=cell["antigen"][input_]

    if num_antigen==0:
        return "Normal"

    mcav=num_cells/num_antigen
    return "Anomaly" if mcav>0.5 else "Normal"

def test_system(migrated,domain,p_anomaly,p_normal,num_trial=100):
    correct_norm=0
    for _ in range(num_trial):
        pattern=construct_pattern("Normal",domain,p_normal,1-p_anomaly)
        class_label=classify_pattern(migrated,pattern)
        correct_norm += 1 if class_label=="Normal" else 0
    print(f"Finished testing Normal inputs {correct_norm}/{num_trial}")
    correct_anom=0
    for _ in range(num_trial):
        pattern=construct_pattern("Anomaly",domain,1-p_normal,p_anomaly)
        class_label=classify_pattern(migrated,pattern)
        correct_anom += 1 if class_label=="Anomaly" else 0
    print(f"Finished testing Anomaly inputs {correct_anom}/{num_trial}")
    return [correct_norm,correct_anom]

def execute(domain,max_iter,num_cells,p_anom,p_norm,thresh):
    migrated=train_system(domain,max_iter,num_cells,p_anom,p_norm,thresh)
    test_system(migrated,domain,p_anom,p_norm)
    return migrated

if __name__ =="__main__":
    # problem configuration
    domain = {}
    domain["Normal"]=[x for x in range(1,51)]
    domain["Anomaly"]=[x*10 for x in range(1,6)]
    domain["Normal"]=[x for x in domain["Normal"] if x not in domain["Anomaly"]]
    p_anomaly=0.70
    p_normal=0.95

    #algorithm configuration
    iterations=100
    num_cells=10
    thresh=[5,15]
    execute(domain,iterations,num_cells,p_anomaly,p_normal,thresh)
```

Comment: Hello @geewynn, and welcome at stack overflow. In order to make it easier for others to help you, can you please describe more precisely what you want to achieve and what is your difficulty?

Comment: The code runs fine, but I am looking for a way to call in my dataset which is in .csv/xlsx format. The algorithm is meant to train and test the dataset as it is said on the code and return if the attributes is an anomaly or normal.

Comment: I see ... and where in the code is data generated or processed? What kind of data is it?

Comment: It is a nsl-kdd data set. Revised version of the kddcup 99 dataset. As for the place where the data is generated, that's where I am having difficulty.